# Salesforce JSON POST works for standard objects by not custom object

Tags: json, salesforce

I am using the Salesforce REST API.  I have created a new custom object within SFDC and want to POST data to it.  I can happily POST JSON documents to the standard SFDC objects such as Account or Contact.  However, when I try posting to my custom object I receive a timeout from SFDC.

Here is the method I am using to perform all POSTS (whether standard or custom)

```
public static BsonDocument PostJSONToSFDC(string uri, BsonDocument postDoc, string method, HPSUtilities.Transformation.Transformation transformation)
        {
            string accessToken = transformation.sfdcAccess.accessToken;
            string instanceUri = transformation.sfdcAccess.instanceUri;

            string uri2 = instanceUri + uri;

            System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri2);
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Method = method;// "POST" or "PATCH"; // a PATCH alternative uses POST with url parm="?_HttpMethod=PATCH"
            req.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + accessToken);

            string postDocAsString = postDoc.ToJson();

            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postDocAsString);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
            os.Close();
            System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            if (resp == null) return null;
            System.IO.StreamReader sr =
                  new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

            string rs = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument doc2;
            if (rs.Equals("") && method.Equals("PATCH", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                // For successful PATCHs (updates), SFDC mysteriously returns a completely empty response.
                // In this case let's create something more meaningful!
                doc2 = new BsonDocument();
                doc2.Add("success", "true");
            }
            else
            {
                doc2 = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>(rs);

            }

            return doc2;
        }
```

Given that this code works when POSTing or PATCHing to SFDC I believe that I must be hitting some sort of SFDC restriction for custom objects.  Is it necessary to mark SFDC custom objects as API-enabled?  Is anyone aware of any other issues that might be causing my timeout?

Comment: what's an example of uri2 when this happens ?

Comment: Is it possible that something is throwing an exception that gets lost rather than it timing out